# How do I specify a path to a data file?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and AJAX.  I am creating a webpage that should display dynamically changing data, and have the webpage refresh when the data in the data file changes.  I did some searching around for an approach and found something that I can use.  It uses two javscript functions `ReloadData` and `processReqChange` (see below).  These functions reside in a file named `reloader.js`.
The code will update the webpage when the data in the file liveData changes. The `reloader.js` file is located in the root of the webpage structure, e.g. same directory as index.html.
The file liveData also is contained in the directory.  if I manually change the data in liveData the data on the webpage will change.  The liveData file is accessed by the line:

```
url = 'liveData?' + now.getTime();
```

The problem is I have a C program that generates a data file in /home/myUsername/liveData. I would like to have the reloader.js read the liveData file in /home/myUsername/.  If I change the url line to:

```
`url = '/home/myUsername/liveData?' + now.getTime();`
```

I get an error stating that it can't find the liveData file.
how can I fix this?
Thanks
J

```
var req;
function reloadData()
{
   var now = new Date();
   url = 'liveData?' + now.getTime(); // file that contains data to be displayed
   try {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } catch (e) {
      try {
         req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
         try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (oc) {
            alert("No AJAX Support");
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
   req.open("GET", url, true);
   req.send(null);
}

function processReqChange()
{
   // If req shows "complete"
   if (req.readyState == 4)
   {
      dataDiv = document.getElementById('currentData');

      // If "OK"
      if (req.status == 200)
      {
         // Set current data text
         dataDiv.innerHTML = req.responseText;

         // Start new timer (1 min)
         timeoutID = setTimeout('reloadData()', 1000);
         // changed 60000 (1 min) to 1000 (1 sec)
      }
      else
      {
         // Flag error
         dataDiv.innerHTML = '<p>There was a problem retrieving data: ' + req.statusText + '</p>';
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's little need to use XHR these days, and certainly not with the old ActiveX fallbacks you have.  The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is [well-supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch).

Next, you will need some form of web server running to be able to serve that file data if you want it accessible via script.  You can't open an arbitrary path on the server from the client.  The server chooses what to data to send in response to a request.

> url = '/home/myUsername/liveData?' + now.getTime()

I assume you're doing the `getTime()` thing on the querystring for cache busting.  Don't bother.  Use the correct [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers instead.

Finally, if you can implement the appropriate server, throw all this away and use the [EventSource API/Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).  This way, the server can notify you immediately when a change occurs, via a very simple API you can implement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'll look into FetchAPI.

Comment: I am running the code on a server.  Given what I am trying to do, can you point me to an example using EventSource?

Comment: @ThreeJeeps Check the link above for eventsource, there are examples on MDN.